# Give 0 height to table view cell using autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have some dummy objects in my data source array.

I don't want to show them on screen. I also cannot remove them from data source array.

I am using proper constraints to get dynamic cell height.

Is there a way I can show a cell of **0 height** for those dummy objects using `AutoLayout`?

Comment: There's some reason why you can not duplicate your datasource without those elements or in runtime decide which will have a cell assigned and just not add a cell for that dummy data?

Comment: why couldn't you remove the dummy data by filtering? that makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of making a **cell height = 0**, you should be thinking about **How to NOT show that cell**.

If you can't duplicate your datasource without the dummy data (because is too big maybe?)

> That's the easiest way by the way.

Then, you should build a function that can give you the correct data given an index.

> For instance:

If you have `[data1, dummy, data2, dummy, data3, data4]`

If you ask for the second element of the datasource, it should respond `data2`
If you ask for the fourth element of the datasource, it should respond `data4`

Of course, you also needs a function that gives you the correct `length` of the datasource without all your dummy data.

> Then just use this functions in proper places (for instance):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfActualDataItems(datasource)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = //Obtain your reusable cell

        let item = actualDataItemIndex(indexPath.row)
        //configureCell will be the function were you place your data to view
        self.configureCell(cell, item)
        return cell
}
```

Comment: Does not fit my requirement.I simply cannot tweak the data source array anyway.I must have all the data at correct array index, since i have related most of cell indexPath with array index for further used logic in my code.

Comment: You can always refer to this functions, you can put them in an abstraction layer over your datasource. An use them when needed.

Comment: @SwappyDwappy if your data is at the point that you **cannot change it in any way or it will break the app** then you need to change your data model because it is broken. This answer is a perfect (and very easy) solution to do what you want.

Comment: @SwappyDwappy, I hardly believe you cannot filter your data array in runtime by non-dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

This is working so far,though i didn't wanted to override heightForRowAtIndexPath :(

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 SomeObjectClass *object = [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 if (object.objectType == DummyDataType) {
    return 0;
 }
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```